# Eigenvalue: How to make it more "eigen"?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional linear space over $F$, $\lambda_1 ... \lambda_m \in F$, $E_1, ..., E_m$ are subspaces of $V$.

The question is, what additional constraints can be given such that a linear map, whose all eigenvalues and corresponding eigenspaces are $\lambda$'s and $E$'s, can be uniquely determined?

I'm asking this because that eigenvalues only give a "partial profile" of a linear map, it characteristics the linear map in an implicit way, this makes me feel that the definition of eigenvalue doesn't deserve its name, though I know maybe it's the best one. (Corrections are welcomed)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the $\lambda_i$ and $E_i$ are given, that the $E_i$ are one-dimensional, and that they span $V$.  Then the linear operator is uniquely determined: any vector $v$ has a unique expression as $v = v_1 + \cdot + v_n$ with the $v_i \in E_i$, and the linear operator maps $v$ to $\lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n.$

(This is the case when the linear operator has $n$ distinct eigenvalues in $F$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.  If $F$ is algebraically closed, then the char. poly. *will* factor into $n$ linear factors, and this is the case that those $n$ factors are distinct; it is the typical, or generic, case.)

Comment: Your answer is beautiful and I am not trying to improve it, which is a more or less futile attempt. But, just to be pedantic, can we not weaken the condition that $E_i$'s are one-dimensional, to that the the linear transformation can be written as diagonal matrices when restricted to $E_i$ and in some appropriate bases for these subspaces?

Comment: @Doldrums: Dear Doldrums, Yes, we could do that.  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

We can generalize the answer given by Matt E. Suppose the eigenspaces are $E_1, \dotsc, E_m \subset V$ with corresponding distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_m$. Let $n_i = \dim E_i$ for all $i$ and $n = \dim V$. Then, the linear transformation is uniquely determined (call it $T$) if $n = n_1 + \dotsb + n_m$. In this case, $V = E_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus E_m$ and so we can choose a basis $\beta_i$ for each $E_i$ and their disjoint union will form a basis $\beta$ for $V$ (well known theorem). Now $v \in \beta \implies v \in \beta_i \subset E_i$ for some $i$. Hence $T(v) = \lambda_i v$. So $T$ applied to the basis $\beta$ is known and thus $T$ is uniquely determined.

If $n > n_1 + \dotsb + n_m$, then there is a subspace $W$ so that $V = E_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus E_m \oplus W$. The linear transformation $T$ is not uniquely determined in this case since $T$ can act in any way on $W$.